# Airflow import task dependency from another file

Tags: python, dependencies, airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

My Airflow has 4 tasks. t1, t2, t3, t4 with task id as task_id1, task_id2, task_id3, task_id4

However, the order of execution of task: t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4
is to be read from a text file.

```
Example: the text file will have:
t1
t2
t3
t4

or

t1
t2
t4
t3

So the order will be: t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4   or  t1 >> t2 >> t4 >> t3

But if i try:
f= open("file_name.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
task1 = lines[0].rstrip()
task2 = lines[1].rstrip()
task3 = lines[2].rstrip()
task4 = lines[3].rstrip()

and then use:
task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> task4

I get error:
×Broken DAG: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'str
```

Any suggestions...?

Actual code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import AirflowException
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

# Create DAG instance
dag = DAG(
'test',
default_args=default_args,
description='A simple tutorial DAG',
catchup=False,
schedule_interval=timedelta(seconds=20),
)


# First task
t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='task1',
bash_command='echo "task 1"',
dag=dag,
)

# Second task
t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='task2',
bash_command='echo "task2"',
dag=dag,
)

# same for t3 and t4

f= open("file_name.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
task1 = lines[0].rstrip()
task2 = lines[1].rstrip()
task3 = lines[2].rstrip()
task4 = lines[3].rstrip()
f.close()

task1 >> task2 >> task4 >> task3
```

file_name.txt can have:
t1
t2
t4
t3

I want this order but this order must come from external file and not in same file.

Comment: dependency is set between operators. Operators are python classes. It's not clear what exactly you have in the text file. is it your dag code or is it just a list of dependency which you should read and apply to your code?

Comment: Probably, first of all, you need to understand what this operator do (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev this is not python bitwise. It's airflow bitshift https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#bitshift-composition

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad. However, OP's data is obviously of `str` type

Comment: The text file has the list of dependency that i want to read and apply to code. If the text file has t1 in 1st line and t2 in 2nd line, then the airflow must work: t1 >> t2
if the text file has t2 in 1st line and t1 in 2nd line, then the airflow must work: t2 >> t1

Comment: @jaus_tail please show the actual code. The sample code you provided doesn't really show the problem. Provide us a minimal code example to reproduce the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This thing helped:
def str_to_class(classname):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], classname)

task1 = ''
task2 = ''
task3 = ''
task4 = ''

f= open("(path_to_scheduler_list.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
task1 = lines[0].rstrip()
task2 = lines[1].rstrip()
task3 = lines[2].rstrip()
task4 = lines[3].rstrip()
f.close()
task1 = str_to_class(task1)
task2 = str_to_class(task2)
task3 = str_to_class(task3)
task4 = str_to_class(task4)

task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> task4
```